# Cannot restore data because of dot in database name

Tags: influxdb, database-backups

InfluxDB-version: 1.6.3

I've created a backup of a database called '**test.mydb**' using the legacy backup format:

```
influxd backup -database <mydatabase> <path-to-backup>
```

The backup went fine but when I tried to restore:

```
sudo influxd restore -db "test.mydb" -newdb "test.mydb" -datadir /var/lib/influxdb/data /home/ubuntu/influxdb/test.mydb/
```

I got the error: `backup tarfile name incorrect format`.

After searching I think it is because of this code in `influxdb/cmd/influxd/restore/restore.go`:

```
// should get us ["db","rp", "00001", "00"] 
    pathParts := strings.Split(filepath.Base(tarFile), ".") 
    if len(pathParts) != 4 { 
        return fmt.Errorf("backup tarfile name incorrect format") 
}
```

It checks how many dots there are in the backup file names. The amount needs to be 4 but because of my database-name the files have 5 dots.

Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find an optimal solution to this problem so I manually copied and pasted the data to InfluxDB.